Shortcut conflict in Codeium's Command with VSCodeVim in visual studio code
I just started using Codeium in VS Code. One of its features is clashing with VSCodeVim. When I enter in the command mode in Codeium (Cmd + I), I can't seem the get out by pressing the Escape key. No other key combo works except collapsing it with the mouse cursor (which is heavily counter productive).
This is what I mean:

Escape key clashes with Codeium command feature when you are also using VSCodeVIM.
The reason for not getting out with the Escape key is that it is intercepted by the VSCodeVim. I tried this by disabling VSCodeVim and it worked fine. I then tried to craft some special keybinding using myriad combinations of "when clause" such as !editorTextFocus || !editorFocus || !inputFocus but nothing seems to work. I have also looked into combining multiple commands like toggleVim but it doesn't work too.
Can you help me craft a keybinding for this purpose. I don't want to choose between VSCodeVim and Codeium. I like them both.
